# Magento Forbidden Error On Backend

Tags: magento-1.9, admin, error

When I Logged in Magento error not display but as I refresh or nevigate to other pages it shows error on every page till three or four navigations then error hide automatically. I access all pages but I wants to know why this error come and how t o solve this.
I have tried below commands but it not works for me

```
    find ./ -type f | xargs chmod 644
    find ./ -type d | xargs chmod 755
    chmod -Rf 777 var
    chmod -Rf 777 media
```

[image]

Comment: Have you checked the Magento and server logs to check if there's an error shown there?

Comment: Have you installed a third party module recently? 
Search for the word **Forbidden** inside **app/code/community/** and **app/code/local/** folders.

Comment: Yes i have install bulk sms third party.How to remove rerror?

Comment: There should be the error massage is set up somehow. You can try to find the word **Forbidden** by the help of any editor and then analyses the code why the error is set.

Comment: Clear your browser cache

Comment: I didn't find that word !!!!

Comment: From looking at the extension's and Magento's code, this seems to be related to a cURL request made with Zend. The word 'Forbidden' can be found in the Zend_Http_Response class for the 403 error code. This would mean that an external server your Magento instance is trying to call forbids it from completing the request. Maybe your 3rd-party account doesn't have your Live IP address whitelisted. I would start by checking that.

Answer (score 0):

Since you've mentioned that Bulk SMS extension is installed, and after that issue occurred, can you try to edit the following file:

`app/etc/modules/Topefekt_Magesms.xml`

and change `<active>true</active>` to `<active>false</active>`.

After that, clear Magento cache, and let us know if it still occurs.

Comment: Extension installed in both Demo and Live site.Error is in only live

Comment: I got it, but it's important to know if it's due to that extension. Also, can you check and paste here PHP versions that you're using on your local, and on your live environment.